# Multiple values in a foreign key

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relationship

Is it possible to have one or more values (or rows) in a foreign key?

Here is my logic:

There are two tables, student and parent. A parent can have more than one child,
(E.g 2016000001 and 2016000002 are both her children) 
so how can I reference those 2 values to my foreign key "children" in my table "parents"

The page will look like this

Hello, Mr. (Parent)

These are your children:
Children 1
Children 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need only one foreign key. Children will have foreign key that references the parent, not the other way around you suggest. E.g.:

Id of parent: 1, ...

Child A: Child id: 1, fk_parent_id: 1, ...

Child B: Child id: 2, fk_parent_id: 1, ...

To answer your question completely, you can use several foreign keys in one table when you want - as several rows (but this is not the case).

Comment: What I mean is that the parents need to have multiple foreign key for his child because there will be a drop-down list on her profile page that will list her children

Comment: To list the children you can use sth. like SELECT FROM Children_tbl WHERE Children_tbl.fk_parent_id = <id of the parent you need>;. This will give you a list of Children of the Parent that you want.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you